# Condition not Satisfied at Groovy

Tags: groovy, bdd, spock, spock-reports

have a problem here, and I'm really tired of try to find an solution...

Every time I use this:

```
Map<Object, Object2> comparisonMap = new HashMap<>()
comparisonMap.put(object, object2)
```

I receive an error message like this:

```
Condition not satisfied:

comparisonMap.put(object, object2)
|             |   |       |
|             |   object  object2
|             null
[object:object2]
```

And I'm really stuck at this. Can someone help me to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be doing this in a `then` block.

`then:` blocks are for asserting something is true.

`Map.put` is a `void` method, so groovy will evaluate this as `false`

The solution is to do this `put` in the correct block...  You don't show your spock test though, so I can't suggest a solution

Comment: Worked! Thank you @tim_yates !

Comment: @MatheusCiaramella Glad to help :-)